# concatenate two arrays using javascripts

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have one page on that page pagination are there initially selectable images are coming after selecting 1 or more images user will click on more activities and he want to select more images from that page then he clicks on confirm button all the selected images will go in one array please help me..

[check this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v1Ow.png)

right now like this coming

localhost/carc_app1/user/modal.php?ids=[{"id":"yoga"},{"id":"aerobics"}][{"id":"net ball"}]

but i want to concatenate both arrays

localhost/carc_app1/user/modal.php?ids=[{"id":"yoga"},{"id":"aerobics"},{"id":"net ball"}]

```
var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
//current page value
 var item_json = JSON.stringify(item) ;


 var page= <?php echo $json_value; ?>;
 var set_image=JSON.stringify(page) ;
 var image=set_image.concat(item_json);
 alert(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Ok. Let's just parse it once instead of turning it
// into a string and reparsing it 57 times needlessly.
var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));

// No!!! What is your obsession with stringify???
//current page value
//var item_json = JSON.stringify() ;

 var page= <?php echo $json_value; ?>;

// NO. just no.
//var set_image=JSON.stringify(page) ;

 var image=page.concat(item);

// You can't alert an array, try console instead
//alert(image);

console.log(image);
```